# Tracking anchor links - Google Analytics

Tags: wordpress, anchor, analytics, tracking

I have a wordpress website and I'm tracking it with google analytics. I need to track the anchors and
have been digging stackoverflow to get some answers. After trying several, I still can't get it to work.  So, what's wrong with this?

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-47361493-1', 'festasdelisboa.com', {'allowAnchor': true});
ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
ga('send', 'pageview');

$(function(){
$("a[href*='http']").each(function() {
                $(this).click(function (ev) {
                    var pageView = '/outgoing/' + $(this).attr('href');
                    _gat._getTrackerByName()._trackEvent('Outbound Links', pageView);
                    var _href = $(this).attr('href');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        location.href = _href;
                    }, 100);
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                });
    });
  $("a[href*='mailto']").each(function() {
                $(this).click(function (ev) {
                    var pageView = '/mailto/' + $(this).attr('href').substring(7);
                    _gat._getTrackerByName()._trackEvent('Mailto', pageView);
                });
    });
  $("a[href*='#']").each(function() {
                $(this).click(function (ev) {
                    var pageView = '/anchor/' + $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
                    _gat._getTrackerByName()._trackEvent('Anchors', pageView);
                });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Was struggling with this for quite a while now. Use the below snippet as part of your Universal Analytics code - found it worked almost immediately for me! My GA reports are showing visits on hashtag anchors in the **Behaviour** >> **Site Content** >> **Content Drilldown** section

```
<script>  
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new
    Date();a=s.createElement(o),  
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-12345678-1', 'auto');   
ga('send', 'pageview');  
// Anchor Tracking snippet start    
    jQuery(document).ready(function () { var
    hashtag = /#\S+/ jQuery('.menu li a').click(function(){ var match =
    jQuery(this).attr('href').match(hashtag); ga('send', 'pageview', '/' +
    match[0]); }) }); 
// Anchor Tracking snippet end  
</script>
```

Found this to be the only workable and easily understandable solution - when it comes to Google's Universal Analytics